# Running RabbitMQ consumer in different thread after consuming message

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to know about the processing of consumed message(thread flow) via Spring  SimpleMessageListenerContainer

I have following understanding

1) Messages consumed via consumer threads. (you can define the consumer thread pools via task executors).

2) the same consumer thread who receives the message process it and gets blocked until it does not finish the execution of handler method.

3) meanwhile other consumer threads gets created to consume the other messages and process those message. The interval to create those consumer threads is based on setStartConsumerMinInterval settings.

Please let me know if I am correct?

The next part is

I want to separate the consuming of message and processing of message in different threads(differnt pools for consuming and processing) how we can do that?
I have tried this way, I have made the handle message of handler as @Async to run it in different threads. Is it a correct way or any better way is available?

The last part is

in my Spring boot application I am both publishing and consuming messages, and I am using a single connection factory(CachingConnectionFactory). Should I use 2 connections factories 1 for publishing and other for consuming? and pass respecctive connection factory to the publishing and consuming beans?

Comment: anyone listining to these tags?

Comment: Does anyone has a answer for this? Any Spring rabbit developers?Please help